# kivy 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_screen'? How do I access values from different screens?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivymd

I'm getting an strange error and spend whole day, still not able to fix this error. I don't know how to access values?

Can you please tell me how do I access values from `ScreenManager`, what I'm doing wrong?

**Error-**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/home/rohit/Desktop/itube/main.py", line 111, in <module>
     Itube().run()
   File "/home/rohit/Desktop/itube/main.py", line 50, in __init__
     caller=self.root.get_screen("homescreen").ids.video_quality,
 AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_screen'
```

**Main.py**

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivymd.uix.filemanager import MDFileManager
from kivymd.toast import toast
from youtube_dl import kv
from kivymd.uix.menu import MDDropdownMenu


Window.size = (450, 740)



class HomeScreen(Screen):
    pass

class SigninScreen(Screen):
    pass




sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(HomeScreen(name='homescreen'))
sm.add_widget(SigninScreen(name='signinscreen'))





class Itube(MDApp):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        Window.bind(on_keyboard=self.events)

        self.path = '/home/rohit'
        self.manager_open = False
        self.file_manager = MDFileManager(
            exit_manager=self.exit_manager,
            select_path=self.select_path,
            previous=True,
        )



        video_quality_options = [{'text': f'items {i}'} for i in range(5)]
        self.dropdown_item = MDDropdownMenu(
            caller=self.root.get_screen("homescreen").ids.video_quality,
            items = video_quality_options,
            width_mult=3,
        )
        self.dropdown_item.bind(on_release=self.menu_callback)


    

    def menu_callback(self, instance_menu, instance_menu_item):
        print(instance_menu, instance_menu_item)

    def option_callback(self, text_of_the_option):
        print(text_of_the_option)


    def file_manager_open(self):
        self.file_manager.show(self.path)  # output manager to the screen
        self.manager_open = True

    def select_path(self, path):
        self.exit_manager()
        toast(path)

    def exit_manager(self, *args):    
        self.manager_open = False
        self.file_manager.close()

    def events(self, instance, keyboard, keycode, text, modifiers):
        '''Called when buttons are pressed on the mobile device.'''

        if keyboard in (1001, 27):
            if self.manager_open:
                self.file_manager.back()
        return True



    def build(self):
        self.main_screen = Screen()

        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Red"

        helper_string = Builder.load_string(kv)
        self.main_screen.add_widget(helper_string)

        return self.main_screen




if __name__ == "__main__":
    Itube().run()
```

**youtube_dl.py**

```
kv = """

ScreenManager:
    HomeScreen:
    SigninScreen:




<HomeScreen>:
    name: 'homescreen'
    video_quality: video_quality

    MDBoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        spacing: 20
        padding: 40


        MDTextFieldRound:
            hint_text: 'Url'
            multline: False
            normal_color: (1, 1, 1, 100)
            color_active: (232/255, 232/255, 232/255, 600)
            



        MDBoxLayout:
            orientation: 'horizontal'
            adaptive_size: True
            spacing: 22
            pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': .99}


            MDRaisedButton:
                text: 'Import from computer'
                icon: "folder"
                elevation_normal: 10
                on_release: app.file_manager_open()
            
            MDRaisedButton:
                text: 'Import from itube cloud'
                elevation_normal: 10

        MDDropdownMenu:
            id: video_quality
            text: 'Select Quality'
            elevation_normal: 10
            on_release: app.dropdown_item.open()
            

        MDLabel:

        MDFloatingActionButton:
            icon: 'archive-arrow-down'
            elevation_normal: 10
            md_bg_color: app.theme_cls.primary_color
            pos_hint: {'center_x': .9, 'center_y': .5}

    

    


<SigninScreen>:
    name: 'signinscreen'


"""
```

Answer (score 1):

You have got half of the code right for accessing a particular screen. The problem in this line...

```
caller=self.root.get_screen("homescreen").ids.video_quality
```

is the `self.root`. The `get_screen` attribute works with the screen manager but `self.root` is not referring to your screen Manager object. So replace `self.root` with the name of your screen manager which is `sm`. So the line should be...

`caller=sm.get_screen("homescreen").ids.video_quality` .

This is only possible if your screen manager object is a assigned to a global variable so that it can be accessed inside your class. But you have already done that. So there isn't anything else to change.

Comment: Still I'm getting error - `'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'`

Comment: How do I fix it?